# log4j encoding utf8

Tags: java, log4j

I use Java and Log4j..

I want to log a string with german special characters, like for example Ü Ä ä etc..
But in my LogFile it appears like this:

```
<E4><FC><F6>
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, rollingFile

log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/home/tomcat/logs/debug.log 
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I think you should convert that string into unicode format and store it

Comment: Is it possible you're opening the log with another encoding (no UTF-8)?

Comment: Does it make a difference how my java File where my Logger is initalized is stored? Do i have to store it in utf8 too?

Comment: No, all that matters is that your compiler and your java file agree on what encoding the source code is in. Once compiled, your log messages are strings, and strings in java have no encoding. Your <E4><FC><F6> content really looks to me like the rollingFile appender somehow got assigned ISO-8859-1 encoding despite your log4j.properties stating otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the below code for storing and retriving the values in the unicode format

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Test {

  public static void printBytes(byte[] array, String name) {
    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
      System.out.println(name + "[" + k + "] = " + "0x"
          + UnicodeFormatter.byteToHex(array[k]));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    String original = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" + "\u00fc" + "C");

    System.out.println("original = " + original);
    System.out.println();

    try {
      byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
      byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes();

      String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
      System.out.println("roundTrip = " + roundTrip);

      System.out.println();
      printBytes(utf8Bytes, "utf8Bytes");
      System.out.println();
      printBytes(defaultBytes, "defaultBytes");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  } // main

}

class UnicodeFormatter {

  static public String byteToHex(byte b) {
    // Returns hex String representation of byte b
    char hexDigit[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    char[] array = { hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f] };
    return new String(array);
  }

  static public String charToHex(char c) {
    // Returns hex String representation of char c
    byte hi = (byte) (c >>> 8);
    byte lo = (byte) (c & 0xff);
    return byteToHex(hi) + byteToHex(lo);
  }

}
```

**Output**

```
Cp1252
original = AêñüC

roundTrip = AêñüC

utf8Bytes[0] = 0x41
utf8Bytes[1] = 0xc3
utf8Bytes[2] = 0xaa
utf8Bytes[3] = 0xc3
utf8Bytes[4] = 0xb1
utf8Bytes[5] = 0xc3
utf8Bytes[6] = 0xbc
utf8Bytes[7] = 0x43

defaultBytes[0] = 0x41
defaultBytes[1] = 0xea
defaultBytes[2] = 0xf1
defaultBytes[3] = 0xfc
defaultBytes[4] = 0x43
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the most posted issues about encoding with Log4J there doesnt seem to be any known issues, therefor i assume you are using a wrong encoding while opening the file, try to check the editor and system encoding maby you will find there an issue.

Comment: i executed locale on my server and it resulted in this:

LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

is this a problem?